# Having issues connecting my client Heroku app to my Server app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I realized I wrote the original question pretty badly. So Im going to try again. So working locally this works perfectly fine. But when I push to Heroku and work on the deployed version, Im getting a CORS error in my console log when I try to login or register a user. My server and client are on two separate heroku apps.

So Im requiring CORS at the top and this is how Im calling inside of my server/index.js

```
app.use(
 cors({
   origin: CLIENT_ORIGIN
  })
);
```

Inside my config vars inside of heroku for my server app. I have CLIENT_ORIGIN connected to my client app URL

This is the error I get inside of the console

Access to fetch at 'https://sheltered-hollows-50081.herokuapp.com/api/login' from origin 'https://nameless-basin-56223.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The sheltered-hollows is my server url and the nameless-basin is my client url.

If more code is needed, I would be happy to show. Just dont know what is neccessary with this error.

Answer (score 1):

Add this npm package on your server
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

import cors in your index.js file

```
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors()); // this will enable cors for all your route.
```

Go through the docs for better understanding.

Comment: Ive tried adding cors to it, but im still getting the same issue

Comment: This should help you out https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors-server/blob/master/app.js